# Taking a HTML form <input> value and using it to modify a <p> tag with Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, input

I am fairly new to Javascript and am trying to create a simple madlib application where a user can input a word through an HTML page and have that word appear in a paragraph tag when the user clicks the "submit" button. I am having troubles displaying the word that the user inputs. I know that I am close but for the life of me cannot figure out what I am missing.

Here is the HTML I am using:

```
 <form>
      <label>Word</label><input id="word"></input>
      <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submitButton"></input>
 </form>

 <p id="story"> A {userWord goes here} is now part of the story </p>
```

And the Javascript:

```
 var word = document.getElementById('word').innerHTML,
     originalStory = document.getElementById('story'),
     button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

 button.onclick = function(){
      replaceStory(word);
 };

 var replaceStory = function(userWord) {
        var story = ("A " + userWord + " is now part of the story");

        return originalStory.innerHTML = story;
 };
```

Here is a JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5c4j2opc/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You had a couple of minor problems. The input type of the submit button should be `button` rather than `submit`. Submit does a post request and refreshes the page with the data received.

Initially you had:
`var word = document.getElementById('word').innerHTML` this would get the initial innerHTML which would be nothing. You have to get the inner text within word every single time the button is clicked to get the most recent text inside the textbox.

Finally, for a input node you should get `.value` rather than `.innerHTML` to get the inner text

html:

```
<form>
    <label>Word</label><input id="word"></input>
    <input type="button" value="submit" id="submitButton"></input>
</form>

<p id="story"> A {userWord goes here} is now part of the story </p>
```

javascript:

```
var word = document.getElementById('word'),
    originalStory = document.getElementById('story'),
    button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

button.onclick = function(){
    replaceStory(word.value);
};

var replaceStory = function(userWord) {
    var story = ("A " + userWord + " is now part of the story");

    return originalStory.innerHTML = story;
};
```

Comment: All of your comments were very useful. Thank you. I just happened to go with this one.

Answer (score 1):

I have made a new JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5c4j2opc/3/ which works.

I changed `type="submit"` to `type="button"` to stop the page refreshing when the button is clicked and moved the word variable to the `replaceStory` function so it doesn't just get called once at the beginning of the script! Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to change two things.

The first is you are using innerHTML in a input element, when you want to access input element you need to get the value not the innerHTML, inputs not have this property.

The second one is that you need to pass the event on the `onclick event` since if you don't do it you can't cancel the submit action and then the page will be submit it automatically and reload the content. Then after you pass the `event` you have to apply `event.preventDefault` which will stop the submit for that button. Other option to avoid this problem would be possible to replace the submit button with a `<button>` tag or `<input type="button">` since not of them will trigger the submit action.

You can see a working example https://jsfiddle.net/5c4j2opc/9/

html -> same you have

javascript

```
var word = document.getElementById('word'),
    originalStory = document.getElementById('story'),
    button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

button.onclick = function(e){
    replaceStory(word.value);
    e.preventDefault();
};

var replaceStory = function(userWord) {
    var story = ("A " + userWord + " is now part of the story");

    return originalStory.innerHTML = story;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You initialize `word`just in the beginning of the script. Besides, that the input value is not `innerHTML`, during that time, the value is empty.

As long as the return value is not set explicitly to `false`, the form will reload the page and overwrite any result.

Change your code:

```
var originalStory = document.getElementById('story'),
button = document.getElementById("submitButton");

button.onclick = function(){
    var word = document.getElementById('word').value;
    replaceStory(word);
    return false;
};

var replaceStory = function(userWord) {
     var story = ("A " + userWord + " is now part of the story");

     originalStory.innerHTML = story;
 };
```

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5c4j2opc/10/)

Answer (score 0):

I advise you to just understand Javascript first, and after then, focus on learning Jquery because it's much more easier and handy.
By the way if you want to do what you said:

You shouldn't use form tag, because you don't want to send something to server-side and you can use div tag as well instead of form tag.

```
<div>
    <label>Word</label>
    <input id="word" type="text"></input>
    <button id="submitButton">Submit</button>
</div>
    <span>A </span><span id="text">{here}</span><span> is now part of the story</span>
```

## Jquery

```
$('#submitButton').click(function(){
    txt = $('#word').val()
    $('#text').text(txt);
});
```

Don't forget to import Jquery Package.

https://jsfiddle.net/softiran/gt8rr5pe/

Answer (score 0):

You could also allow the user to change your story directly. I know this may not use an input tag, but it was very useful to me.

```
<div id="story">Once upon a time there was a man named
<p id="added" contenteditable="true" title="Click to change">
Bill</p>. He liked to eat tacos.</div>
```

I used this in a code that changed the name of the main character of a story into a user-selected name and allowed them to download the story. Hope this helps! All the user has to do is click the name "Bill" and they will be able to change the name to anything they want.